# Possible to set cookie just accessible by javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, cookies, local-storage

Hi i have an extension works under facebook. i use localStorage for storage some keys when needed. Now i want to port my extension to internet explorer (a.k.a Js hell). I think most of IE versions have no localStorage support so i found that gist

https://raw.github.com/gist/350433/c9d3834ace63e5f5d7c8e1f6e3e2874d477cb9c1/gistfile1.js

It works with cookie. But facebook deletes unused cookies by Set-Cookie header ?

any suggestions? thanks.

Comment: IE7, even 6 and 5 supported something called userData. Its basically a non-standard localStorage. You could use something like [amplify.storage](http://amplifyjs.com/api/store/) to abstract that away.